# html button element won't accept jquery ui effects

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-effects

so, I have a button element like this:

```
button {
    margin-top: 20px;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding:10px 15px;
    background:#33B5E5;
    border:1px solid #33B5E5;
    color:white;
}

<button type="button">Send</button>
```

(I use the type button so it doesn't submit anything on click, as I'll later use it for ajax)

I want that button to be animated on click, so I use:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $(this).effect( "highlight", {color:"#669966"}, 3000 );
});
```

but the button doesn't do anything on click.

The button does work if instead of an effect I do something like showing an alert, though.

Here's my header, too:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="web.css">
  <title>asdf</title>
  <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.min.css">
  <script src="external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-ui.theme.min.css"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Off-topic: It appears that you're loading jQuery twice.

Comment: `highlight()` modifies an element's background color. Does your button have styling that would prevent this?

Comment: Try changing this with `button`. Also, try surrounding it in an document.ready function.

Comment: @isherwood your link needs the "http://" in front, we can't click it.

Comment: @isherwood I don't think my styling has anything that would prevent the effect: button{
margin-top: 20px;
cursor:pointer; 
padding:10px 15px; 
background:#33B5E5; 
border:1px solid #33B5E5;
color:white; 
}

Comment: @Nicolas I tried both, the problem persists.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/cca6R/

Comment: Works with your CSS, too: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/cca6R/5/

Comment: Please try to recreate the problem in a fiddle of your own. Also check the console for errors.

Comment: Fixed. It was a mistake on my part, see the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0):

What about changing this:

```
<script src="jquery-ui.theme.min.css"></script>
```

to this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.theme.min.css" />
```

Comment: Nope, no improvement. It's frustrating to see that it works in jfiddle with the exact same code though.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/qWZeB/).

That said, it must be something with the way you are linking jQuery UI; it's difficult to tell whether you've done that correctly because you're linking to local files.

Really, all you should need in your `head` is this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Also, it appears that you've linked to a stylesheet in a `<script>` tag:

```
<script src="jquery-ui.theme.min.css"></script>
```

It should be in a `<link>` tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.theme.min.css"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

I'm sorry guys, it was an issue with the external files, they had been copied in the wrong folder of my server.

Thanks for your help anyway, and sorry for wasting your time!